# Finding the longest circular path of a given length when all nodes are connected

Tags: algorithm

During an assignment I wanted to find the longest circular path for a given length.
Use the image below as an example. We want to find the longest possible circular path of a given length.

[image]

e.g. for length 3 the longest circular path is DBED or EDBE.

I proposed as a way to find the longest path a modified version of Dijkstra.
The differences are:

1. Instead of min is searching for the max in each step.
2. When the step is length-1 the algorithm stops and goes back to the starting point and add the distance from the last point to the total path length.
3. Do it with every node as a starting point.

I have checked the algorithm for 6 nodes and length up to 5 and it worked, but I cannot check if it's true for a larger number like 100.

My professor said that Dijkstra is not what you looking for for that problem and an algorithm finding Hamiltonian circuits would be more effective. I believe he is right and as in a lot of threads as [Dijkstra's algorthm modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863818/dijkstras-algorthm-modification) people pointed that Dijkstra's algorithm is not capable of finding the longest path.

But although it is true that Dijkstra is not what I am looking for; the above case is a very special case because all nodes are connected and the modified version checks for every point as a staring point and also a circular path for a given length.

Finally, my question is why the modified version can't find the right solution for this and only this special case.

Comment: How would Dijkstra's with max instead of min even work? The important invariant of Dijkstra's is that you can add a vertex to the subset of visited vertices because you know taking a detour won't give you a shorter path. In your example, starting from A, which neighbor node do you add to the set of visited vertices? None of them will yield a longest path.

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by 'circular path'? Are you allowed to visit a vertex more than once?

Comment: Will every input graph have all-to-all connections?

Comment: @AndyG Yes every input path will have all to all connections.

Comment: To clarify what I think @ColonelPanic is asking: can a given path contain a cycle? That is would BEDBED be a valid guess for a path length of 6?

Comment: @Heuster For length 3 the way the algorithm goes is from A to B since it it the most distant place to go, then it goes to D and then back to A since length 3 is achieved. Next step is to start from B and so on.. In the end DBE or EBD will be returned as the longest path.

Comment: @AndyG Yes every input path will have all to all connections.

Comment: @Colonel Panic No you are not allowed except when you have covered the distance, then you are allowed to visit again the starting point. Maybe circular is a wrong definition but what I meant was that the starting point is also the ending point.You visit each place once. Thanks Andy for the clarification BEDBED is not a valid guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dijkstra algorithm finds only the shortest path between 2 points and to do so it can skip vertices. A hamiltonian cycle visit each vertices only once and is a cycle. In an Euler path you might passes a vertex twice.

Comment: Thanks, what I probably need is a hamiltonian cycle. But I just wanted to know why I am wrong in the assumption above. Just food for thought for me and whoever stumbles on this post

Comment: When it's helpful can you accept the answer? This is big thanks for me!?